# Hibernate does not verify OneToOne relation

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

I have the bellow standard one to one relation.

```
@Entity
class EntityA {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "a")
    EntityB b;
}

@Entity
class EntityB {
    @OneToOne(joinColumn = "a_id")
    EntityA a;
}
```

I have tested Hibernate doesn't seem to prevent me from inserting more than one `EntityB` with the same `EntityA`. It doesn't give any `RuntimeException` until I try to retrieve where it throws the Exception

> more than one row found

Wouldn't it be better if we could force hibernate to strictly maintain **one to one** relation? Is that possible from the **ORM** layer Without adding `Unique constraint` on the `foreign key`?

Thanks is advance.

Comment: *Without adding Unique constraint on the foreign key*: that's the only thing that can guarantee the uniqueness. Just do that.

Comment: Yes, I would probably do that, but that would be on the DB layer, not one the ORM layer, I was expecting to find something that would prevent me from ORM layer.

Comment: There isn't such a thing. The ORM relies on the database to enforce constraints, because that's the only place where they can be safely and efficiently enforeced.